# Returning all attribute names inside of a document via Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbyclassname, roblox

I am developing a Chrome Extension for a website known as **[Roblox](http://www.roblox.com/)**.

The forum has a lot of advantages, and some disadvantages. There have been other Chrome Extensions for this site, but they just do not seem to fulfill my needs.

This was my first encounter with making a legit Chrome extension, so I went ahead and read the entire wiki.

But when i tested my code it didn't work. This was a little odd because the error log didn't display any errors or `console.log()` lines.

What am I doing incorrectly? 
 
 
 
manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Roblox ID Display", 
    "version": "1.0", 
    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "description": "Roblox ID Display displays the ID of forum posts.",
    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }, 
    "permissions": [
        "http://www.roblox.com/" 
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js:

```
var elements = Array.filter(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(elem){
    n = elem.getAttribute("name");
    x = n.replace([0-9]i, ""); 
    console.log(n); 
    console.log(x); 
    console.log(x == n); 
    return x == n;
});
var names = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i]); 
    names.push(elements[i].getAttribute("name")); 
}
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
    console.log(names[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Let me guess: The actual URL is not `....ShowPost.aspx`, but rather `....ShowPost.aspx?....`. If so, you need to append an asteriks to your `matches` URL pattern.

Comment: What @RobW means to say is to try `"matches": ["http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx*"]`